# Class Not found errors in dependencies for AWS simple email services

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, wso2-micro-integrator, sts

I am using Java. I am using an "assume role" for sending email. When the below code is deployed, a `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown.

```
\[2024-01-08 09:57:14,179\] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ClassMediatorFactory} - Error in instantiating class : org.capgemini.ciap.core.CoreJSONPayloadUtils 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: software/amazon/awssdk/auth/credentials/AwsCredentialsProvider 
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) 
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137) 
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342) 
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556) 
at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ClassMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(ClassMediatorFactory.java:110)
```

This is my java code.

```java
    import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.*;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.SesClient;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.ses.model.*;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.StsClient;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.AssumeRoleRequest;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.StsException;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.AssumeRoleResponse;


    import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsBasicCredentials;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsCredentialsProvider;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.StaticCredentialsProvider;
    import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.Credentials;




    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    static void awsMailService(MessageContext context) {

    context.setProperty("ERROR_CODE", "");
    log.info("inside SendSESMail Java class");

    
    log.info(">> AWS_ROLE_ARN: " + context.getProperty("AWS_ROLE_ARN"));
    log.info(">> AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME: " + context.getProperty("AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME"));
    log.info(">> AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE: " +   context.getProperty("AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE"));


    try {

        String roleArn = context.getProperty("AWS_ROLE_ARN").toString();
        String roleSessionName = context.getProperty("AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME").toString();
        
        
        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;

        
        StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create())
            .build();


        Credentials myCreds = assumeGivenRole(stsClient, roleArn, roleSessionName);

        AwsSessionCredentials awsCreds = AwsSessionCredentials.create(myCreds.accessKeyId(), myCreds.secretAccessKey(), roleSessionName);

        
        SesClient sesClient = SesClient.builder()
            .region(region)
            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds))
            .build();

        
        String sender = "xxx.com";
        String recipient = "xxxx";

        
        Content subject = Content.builder().data("Test Email").build();
        Content body = Content.builder().data("This is a test email").build();
        Body emailBody = Body.builder().text(body).build();
        Message message = Message.builder().subject(subject).body(emailBody).build();

        
        SendEmailRequest sendEmailRequest = SendEmailRequest.builder()
            .source(sender)
            .destination(Destination.builder().toAddresses(recipient).build())
            .message(message)
            .build();

        SendEmailResponse sendEmailResponse = sesClient.sendEmail(sendEmailRequest);

        
        System.out.println("Email sent! Message ID: " + sendEmailResponse.messageId());
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        log.error("The email was not sent. Error message in java code: ", th);
        context.setProperty("ERROR_CODE", "500");
        context.setProperty("ERROR_MESSAGE", th.getMessage());
        context.setProperty("ERROR_DETAIL", "Error in java code: awsMailService");
    }

    }

    public static Credentials assumeGivenRole(StsClient stsClient, String roleArn, String        roleSessionName) {
    AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
        .roleArn(roleArn)
        .roleSessionName(roleSessionName)
        .build();

    AssumeRoleResponse roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
    Credentials myCreds = roleResponse.credentials();

    return myCreds;
    }
```

Comment: I am using below dependency.                                                                          
       <dependency>
   <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
   <artifactId>ses</artifactId>
   <version>2.22.12</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
   <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
   <version>2.22.12</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: Please [edit] and add the dependency to your post instead of adding it in the comments.

Comment: You need the `software.amazon.awssdk:auth` dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/auth/2.22.12 Note that this version has known security issues, and you should upgrade to the latest version, which probably means you need to update your sts dependency too so the versions are reliably compatible.